# Average at a timeframe

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that goes like this,

```
Datatime                 Values
2014-10-13 18:50:00     2
2014-10-13 18:51:00     4
2014-10-13 18:52:00     64
2014-10-13 18:53:00     123
2014-10-13 18:54:00     12312
```

(this is just a part of the database, it has 1000+ columns so I just get a small part of it)

What I wanted to do is get the average of column "Values" at a 15 minute interval

Comment: Please edit your question and provide desired results.  The average "at a specific amount of minutes X" really doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well your request the below instruction will solve your problemm:

```
 SELECT AVG(Values) FROM YourTableName where Datatime = "2014-10-13 18:51:00";
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to convert the time to the nearest 15-minute interval and then use `group by`:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( (TIME_TO_SEC(datetime) DIV 900) * 900) AS Nearest15,
       avg(values)
FROM table
GROUP BY SEC_TO_TIME( (TIME_TO_SEC(datetime) DIV 900) * 900)
ORDER BY Nearest15;
```